# Guardar archivo almacenamiento externo

Tags: java, android-studio

sigo con mi pequeño proyecto, en una PDA con Android 5.1 este código funciona perfectamente guarda el archivo con el nombre y formato deseado, pero al probarlo con otra "igual" la diferencia es que tiene Android 7.1, y simplemente no me guarda el archivo, y tampoco genera ningún error que yo vea.

```
 try {
        File tarjetaSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Toast.makeText(this, tarjetaSD.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // ruta marcada   /storage/emulated/0   correcto
        File rutaArchivo = new File(tarjetaSD.getPath(), nombre);
        OutputStreamWriter crearArchivo = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo));

        crearArchivo.write(saludo);
        crearArchivo.flush();

        Toast.makeText(this, rutaArchivo.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    // ruta + nombre   /storage/emulated/0/test.csv   



        crearArchivo.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        etOrigen.setText("");
        etEdad.setText("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo guardar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

He estado buscando y leyendo y parece ser que con api 25 o superior que es mi caso es necesario asignar permiso de escritura en el momento aparte de en el Manifiest , he visto algunos códigos pero no tengo claro en que parte debo añadir ese código

Este código está en esta dirección de este mismo foro : 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42842648/write-to-external-storage-on-android-7`

```
permission=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTANAL_STORAGE);
    permission=ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACCESS_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_STATE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // Write to the storage (ex: call appendByteBuffer(byte[] data) here)

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please grant permission.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas esta es la solución que encontré, la he probado con otra app con la que también guardo un fichero y funciona ya me pide y otorga permiso

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```